# "Any function on finite lists that is defined by pairing the desired result with the argument list can always be redefined in terms of fold"

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

I was reading through the paper [A tutorial on the universality and
expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf), and am stuck on the section about generating tuples. After showing of how the normal definition of `dropWhile` cannot be defined in terms of fold, an example defining `dropWhile` using tuples was proved:

```
dropWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropWhile p = fst . (dropWhilePair p)

dropWhilePair :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
dropWhilePair p = foldr f v
  where
    f x (ys,xs) = (if p x then ys else x : xs, x : xs)
    v           = ([], [])
```

The paper states:

> In fact, this result is an instance of a
>   general theorem (Meertens, 1992) that states that any function on finite lists that is
>   defined by pairing the desired result with the argument list can always be redefined
>   in terms of fold, although not always in a way that does not make use of the original
>   (possibly recursive) definition for the function.

I looked at [Meerten's Paper](http://www.kestrel.edu/home/people/meertens/publications/papers/Paramorphisms.pdf) but do not have the background (category theory? type theory?) and did not quite find how this was proved.

Is there a relatively simple "proof" why this is the case? Or just a simple explanation as to why we can redefine all functions on finite lists in terms of fold if we pair the results with the original list.

Comment: This might be a better fit for the cs theory site

Answer (score 2):

Given the remark that you can / may need to use the original function inside, the claim as stated in your question seems trivial to me:

```
rewriteAsFold :: ([a] -> (b, [a])) -> [a] -> (b, [a])
rewriteAsFold g = foldr f v where
    f x ~(ys,xs) = (fst (g (x:xs)), x:xs)
    v            = (fst (g []), [])
```

EDIT: Added the `~`, after which it seems to work for infinite lists as well.

Comment: Looking at the original paper rather than the quoted passage, it seems to be making the claim that any function `f :: [a] -> b` can be written as `fst . (foldr f' v :: [a] -> (b, [a]))` for some `f', v`, which is stronger than what you've got here.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield Not really, it's just that I'm rewriting `g = \l -> (f l, l)` instead of your `f` itself, because that's how the question was stated. The stronger version follows immediately.