# Generalizing fold such that it becomes expressive enough to define any finite recursion?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, generic-programming, fold, proof

So, there is something known as a "universal property of fold", stating exactly following:

`g [] = i; g (x:xs) = f x (g xs)` <=> `g = fold f i`

However, as you probably now, there are rare cases like `dropWhile`, which can not be redefined as `fold f i` **unless you generalize it**.

The simplest yet obvious way to generalize is to redefine universal property:

`g' y [] = j y; g' y (x:xs) = h y x xs (g' y xs)` <=> `g' y = fold (?) l`

---

At this point I can make my assumption: I assume existence of somewhat function `p :: a -> b -> b`, which would satisfy the equation `g' y = fold p l`. Let's try to solve given equation with help of universal property, mention at the very beginning:

- `g' y [] = j y = fold p l [] = l` => `j y = l`
- `g' y (x:xs) = h y x xs (g' y xs) = fold p l (x:xs) = p x (fold p l xs) = p x (g' y xs)` => letting `rs = (g' y xs)`, **`h y x xs rs = p x rs`, which is wrong**: `xs` occurs freely from the left and thus equality can't hold.

---

Now let me try to interpret result I've came up with and ask question. 
I see that the problem is `xs` **emerging as unbound variable**; it's true for various situations, including above mentioned `dropWhile`. Does it mean that the only way that equation can be solved is by "extending" `rs` to a pair of `(rs, xs)`? In other words, `fold` accumulates into **tuple rather than a single type** (ignoring the fact that tuple itself is a single type)? Is there any other way to generalize bypassing pairing?

Comment: Actually you *can* implement `dropWhile` with the standard `fold`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you give an example?

Comment: sorry, somehow I mixed `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yeah. there is no way to implement `dropWhile`, it can be proven by simple calculation with help of universal property from the OP. in order to implement `dropWhile` one has to generalize to a pair `(rs, ys)`, than it's fine. the problem there is exactly the same: unbound `xs`.

Comment: I am sorry, but could someone explain for a simple man, what `fold` is the talk about? Right or left?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov It is a right fold -- the canonical way of tearing down a (cons) list.

Comment: @duplode I am then having trouble reconciling this question with the lengthy treatment of `foldr` in [The Monad.Reader Issue 6](https://wiki.haskell.org/wikiupload/1/14/TMR-Issue6.pdf). To my understanding of the article, there are several ways to build a `dropWhile` from a `foldr`.

Comment: A relevant discussion (for both you and @IgnatInsarov , I guess): [*“Any function on finite lists that is defined by pairing the desired result with the argument list can always be redefined in terms of fold”*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25146643/2751851)

Comment: For what it is worth: if we flip arguments, we have `flip dropWhile = foldr (\x k p -> if p x then k p else x : k (\_ -> False)) (\_ -> [])`

Comment: @chi, wow, pretty unexpected one! now the question is: can it be considered as a valid generalization of fold, or not? Have to think more about it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as you say. The universal property says that `g [] = i; g (x:xs) = f x (g xs)` iff `g = fold f i`. This can't apply for a straightforward definition of `dropWhile`, as the would-be `f :: a -> [a] -> [a]` depends not just on the element and accumulated value at the current fold step, but also on the whole list suffix left to process (in your words, "`xs` emerg[es] as an unbound variable"). What can be done is twisting `dropWhile`so that this dependency on the list suffix becomes manifest in the accumulated value, be it through a tuple -- cf. [`dropWhilePair` from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25146643/2751851), with `f :: a -> ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])` -- or a function -- as in [chi's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138464/generalizing-fold-such-that-it-becomes-expressive-enough-to-define-any-finite-re#comment85285420_49138464)...

```
dropWhileFun = foldr (\x k -> \p -> if p x then k p else x : k (const False)) (const [])
```

... with `f :: a -> ((a -> Bool) -> [a]) -> ((a -> Bool) -> [a])`.

At the end of the day, the universal property is what it is -- a fundamental fact about `foldr`. It is no accident that not all recursive functions are immediately expressible through `foldr`. In fact, the tupling workaround your question brings to the table directly reflects the notion of paramorphism (for an explanation of them, see [*What are paramorphisms?* and its exquisite answer by Conor McBride](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13317242/2751851)). At face value, paramorphisms are generalisations of catamorphisms (i.e. a straightforward fold); however, it only takes a slight contortion to implement paramorphisms in terms of catamorphisms. (Additional technical commentary on that might be found, for instance, in Chapter 3 of [*Categorical Programming With Inductive and Coinductive Types*, Varmo Vene's PhD thesis](https://kodu.ut.ee/~varmo/papers/thesis.pdf).)

Comment: +1 for you answer, though I have few remarks. First of all, you don't need "*iff* `g = fold f i`. *iff* is redundant simply because having `g` guarantees existence of corresponding `fold f i`, where both `f` and `i` completely determined by `g`'s definition. Please correct me, if I am mistaken here. The other thing is that you showed 2 different ways to implement `dropWhile`, hence the question "are they both can be accepted as valid generalization?" arises... and I don't have any answer yet, got no idea how to reason about this particular problem.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov (1) The iff (or, equivalently, the <=> in your question) is not redundant -- the property is an equivalence, even though the right-to-left direction is trivial. (2) They are both correct implementations of `dropWhile`, so they are both valid. The follow-up question I would suggest instead would be whether `dropWhileFun` can be more straightforwardly expressed through some other recursion scheme, similarly to how `dropWhilePair` can be expressed as a paramorphism.