# RxJs: Merge all values after concapMap so they emit together in the subscribe "next" event?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have set up an observable to basically call an endpoint for each item in an array but I then need to merge together the items before publishing to to the subscribe "next". Right now, the subscribe "next" is executed N number of times depending on the total in the array, any ideas ? Here is my code

```
   from(items)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(item => {    
          return this.httpClient.get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
        }),
        tap(items => {
          debugger
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          debugger
        },
        error => {
          debugger
        }
      )
```

I tried placing a mergeAll before the TAP but it crashes.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `forkJoin()` or `toArray()`.

Comment: How do you use `item` under the `HTTP` request?

Comment: Item is not being used under the HTTP request right now, but its only a test url. But eventually there is an id under item and i will call an endpoint using this id

Comment: @martin use forkJoin ? If I place forkJoint after the concatMap pipe, it doesn't seem to work, do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `toArray()` would accumulate an array of responses,
- `reduce()` can be used in order to reproduce `toArray()` behavior in a more flexible way: you can apply more sophisticated merging logic (like ignore duplicate entries or whatsnot).

P.S. Not sure, but it might be the case that you've misdesigned something. Rather than use accumulation there you might want a higer order observable such that your consumer does not require array explicitly and underlying logic is more decoupled.

---

All right, the thing is that you can think that `toArray()` is quite special case of reduction. Let's start from the signature: `reduce(accumulator: function, seed: any): Observable`. So `seed`, the second parameter, is initial value you start from (and in case the stream you're trying to reduce is empty `seed` is the only value will will get as a result). In case of `toArray()` `seed` is just `[]` - an... empty... array! Then the first parameter, `accumulator`, it is a function that takes `(result, current)` - two paramers, where `result` represents the result so far and the `current` represents "not yet reduced" element of a stream. So the type of `result` is `array` and the type of `current` can be whatever the type of your stream is, in your case - http responses I guess. `(result, current) => { result.Add(current); return result; }` - that's the simplest possible implementation, which will give you `toArray()` behavior. However, you could do more, like decide not to add `current` if it is outdated or invalid, that's why I told you that `reduce()` is much more powerful.

P.P.S. If you'd like to know how deep the rabbit's hole is, than `reduce` (also known like `foldl` in Haskell and other functional languages) is basically the recursion pattern. Most of the stuff (but definitely not everything!) that defined via recursion, can be rewritten as a `reduce` with appropariate `seed` and `accumulator` parameters; for example, it is quite easy to implement `filter` throught reduction. [See this question to find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138464/generalizing-fold-such-that-it-becomes-expressive-enough-to-define-any-finite-re).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example with reduce ? I have tried toArray and that seems to work.